# VirtualBox Centos Not having network connection

Tags: virtualbox, unix, centos, ethernet, osx-mavericks

After reading several posts on the above topic, i was forced to post this question because i m still stuck.

I am running internet connection on MAC OS X el captain(wifi) and trying to run internet in Centos in virtual box
Following are my network settings in the virtual box menu
`Adapter 1
Attached to : Bridged Adapter
en0: Wifi(AirPort)
Promiscous Mode : Allow all`

and config in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

`DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
BROADCAST="10.0.1.255"
DNS1="10.0.1.60"
DNS2="8.8.8.8"
GATEWAY="10.0.1.1"
mHWADDR="Hardware address"
IPADDR="IP"
NETMASK="NETMASK"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ON_BOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"`
`#UUID="UUID"`

service network restart gives
`Determining IP informartion for eth0 ... failed:no link present.Check cable?`

**Please Help**

Answer (score 0):

I'd only put the below to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
NETWORKING=yes
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
```